# Protractor - How to get the element that I just performed an action?

Tags: angularjs

I am using protractor to write some e2e tests for an app written in AngularJS, and I want to perform the following task:

```
element(by.id('btn1')).click().then(function() {
     // I want to get the element that I just clicked, and check its label
     // How I can pass (if possible) the element to the then() function?
});
```

currently what I do is:

```
element(by.id('btn1')).click().then(function() {
     expect(element(by.id('btn1')).getText()).toBe('cancel');
});
```

Thanks in advance,
Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the [`click()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click) promise is of type `webdriver.promise.Promise.<void>` so there's nothing passed in to the resolver.

Simply store the element reference in a variable to re-use it

```
var btn = element(by.id('btn1'));
btn.click().then(function() {
    expect(btn.getText()).toEqual('cancel');
});
```